# Why we need to mock static class before every test case in same class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, junit4, spring-test

I have a test class with two test cases . I am using Junit 4. My these test cases are using static class. So I mocked  a static class in @BeforeClass method so that it is only mocked once before the start of execution of test cases. but in this case only first test case works fine and rest of all test cases fails. so for that I mocked my static class in @Before method so that it is been mocked before every test case execution. So I want to understand that why is there need to mock the static class before every test case and why cant we mock it only once before start of execution of class.

```
import com.walmart.fulfillment.encryption.logging.HttpThreadBusinessContext;
import com.walmart.rxorderdetailsfulfillment.data.LabelOverFlowOrderRepo;
import com.walmart.rxorderdetailsfulfillment.models.entity.LabelOverFlowOrder;
import com.walmart.rxorderdetailsfulfillment.models.entity.LabelOverFlowPK;
import com.walmart.rxorderdetailsfulfillment.models.request.LabelOverFlowRequest;
import com.walmart.rxorderdetailsfulfillment.models.response.LabelOverFlowResponse;
import com.walmart.rxorderdetailsfulfillment.util.LabelOverFlowUtility;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({LabelOverFlowUtility.class,HttpThreadBusinessContext.class,LabelOverFlowOrderRepo.class,LabelOverFlowResponse.class,LabelOverFlowOrder.class,LabelOverFlowPK.class})
public class LabelOverFlowRequestHandlerTest {

    static int count =0;

    LabelOverFlowRequest labelOverFlowRequest;

    @InjectMocks
    LabelOverFlowRequestHandler labelOverFlowRequestHandler;

    @Mock
    HttpThreadBusinessContext httpThreadBusinessContext;

    @Mock
    LabelOverFlowOrderRepo labelOverFlowOrderRepo;

    @Mock
    LabelOverFlowResponse labelOverFlowResponse;

    @Mock
    LabelOverFlowOrder labelOverFlowOrder;

    @Mock
    LabelOverFlowPK labelOverFlowPK;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void initialization(){
        //PowerMockito.mockStatic(LabelOverFlowUtility.class);

    }

    @Before
    public void initialization_Before_Every_Test(){
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LabelOverFlowUtility.class);
        labelOverFlowRequest = LabelOverFlowRequest.builder().textOverFlow(true).warningOverFlow(true).rxFillId(555).siteNbr(5550).countryCode("US").build();

    }

    /**
     * This test case is use to check success is returned after saving data to DB.
     */
    @Test
    public void processSaveLabelOverFlowResquestWithSuccess() {

        when(LabelOverFlowUtility.getLabelOverFlowPK(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(labelOverFlowPK);
        when(LabelOverFlowUtility.getLabelOverFlowOrder(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(labelOverFlowOrder);

        when(labelOverFlowOrderRepo.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(labelOverFlowResponse);
        when(LabelOverFlowUtility.getLabelOverFlowResponse(Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();
        Mockito.doReturn(labelOverFlowOrder).when(labelOverFlowOrderRepo).save(Mockito.any());

        assertTrue(labelOverFlowRequestHandler.processSaveLabelOverFlowResquest(labelOverFlowRequest).getResponseText().equals("success"));

    }

    /**
     * This test case is ued to check if data is not saved to DB
     */
    @Test
    public void processSaveLabelOverFlowResquestWithFailure() {

        when(LabelOverFlowUtility.getLabelOverFlowPK(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(labelOverFlowPK);
        when(LabelOverFlowUtility.getLabelOverFlowOrder(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(labelOverFlowOrder);

        when(labelOverFlowOrderRepo.save(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(labelOverFlowResponse);
        when(LabelOverFlowUtility.getLabelOverFlowResponse(Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();
        Mockito.doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(labelOverFlowOrderRepo).save(Mockito.any());

        assertTrue(labelOverFlowRequestHandler.processSaveLabelOverFlowResquest(labelOverFlowRequest).getResponseText().equals("failure"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Why would  you think you need to mock your static class?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem The reason for mocking this class is that few methods in this class gives output on the base of input, so we are mocking it to get output of our will in this test case. For example there is one method which creates response for both success and failure. So we have mocked that method to get response according to our scenario in test case.

Comment: Well, there's no reason at all why you can't mock it just once, in a method with the `@BeforeClass` annotation.  Try it!  The mock itself would have to be static, of course.

Answer (score 0):

`LabelOverFlowUtility.class` is a static class, there should be no need to mock it at all if the methods are deterministic(given same input same thing happens).

I may be misunderstanding how this class operates.

Comment: The reason for mocking this class is that few methods in this class gives output on the base of input, so we are mocking it to get output of our will in this test case. For example there is one method which creates response for both success and failure. So we have mocked that method to get response according to our scenario in test case.